# CSS won't load in IE8

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I'm having problems with IE8 loading my child theme CSS. It loads the Google fonts and my other custom CSS on the home page (hazelhomemaker.com) but it won't load my CSS settings for the breadcrumbs or my Google fonts on my secondary pages: hazelhomemaker.com/about and hazelhomemaker.com/contact. In the footer widgets, the links are coded for no underline, but they are showing that way on the home page and the secondary pages. ???

I'm using a Headway theme in Wordpress. This issue has been troubleshooted for days by several different developers and no one can figure it out. So if someone here can, you truly are brilliant in my book.

We've ruled out plug-in conflicts. We've ruled out CSS coding errors to the best of our ability. Headway is insistent this is not a problem on their end. I am at my wit's end.

Help would be much appreciated.

D

Comment: Just to give a little more clarity, the CSS on the secondary pages appears to load for a few seconds, but then it reverts back.

Comment: It's loading fine in chrome. Will have to test in IE8..

Comment: I opened the website from IE8 and yeah it seems IE8 is not accepting the CSS. I'm sorry but no one would be able to help you here because what you ask requires a lot of debugging and testing which only your Web Admin has the rights to do. Hire some professionals to do this work for you. If you can't, mail me your website's code in a ZIP format, I'll debug and test it on my server and if I succeed, I'll mail you back my results. :)

Comment: @Sean - Thanks for the reply. When you say Web Admin, do you mean WordPress or the theme developer or the owner of the website? I'd love to get your help. With it being a WordPress site, I'm not sure what to send you other than my CSS coding and PHP add-on scripts.Can you work with that and my source code or do you need more info?

Comment: Any would do fine, though, Web admin can only help if he/she is a web developer. You should consult the theme developer I guess, he/she must know better about this. :)

Comment: The `.php`, `.html,` `.js` and `.css` and other related files would be enough if you want my help. Pack everything in a zip file and attach it in a mail.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and force load it in the header?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://hazelhomemaker.com/wp-content/themes/headway-schematic/style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I've seen the source code, it's already there, and she has a problem with IE8 not loading the CSS so edit your answer.